# Something along the lines of coalescing values in a column to flatten a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has multiple records per locId. Each record has a number of attributes which may or may not be populated. I'd like to "flatten" this table to return a single row for each locId, and with the most recent **populated** value. That is, even if a newer record is NULL for a given attribute column, I would want to return the most recent non-NULL value. For example:

My table:

```
| locId | col1 | col2 | date |
| ----- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1     | d    | NULL | 2022 |
| 1     | NULL | b    | 2022 |
| 1     | NULL | c    | 2023 |
| 1     | a    | NULL | 2024 |
```

Desired result

```
| locId | col1 | col2 | date |
| ----- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1     | a    | c    | 2024 |
```

Unfortunately I don't have requirements clearly defined, so I'm trying to start with something sensible and send to stakeholders to clarify. In likeliness, the requirements will be more complicated as there are other columns I'd like to use for prioritization, but I'm at a loss trying to create this more basic approach.

Note: I can't use `MAX()` with `GROUP BY` because the values in col1 and col2 are descriptive and not in any order.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and does the table have a column, which clearly defines the order of the inserted rows?

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 12, and I would have a datetime column.

Comment: @siggemannen Testing it out now, looks like it works on my version of SQL Server (2014). Thank you!